# Postgres: Get the Complement of Distinct Entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Currently I can get distinct entries from a table like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (abc.entry) abc.* FROM table abc
    JOIN table1 def ON abc.entry = def.entry
WHERE def.created >= 'some_date' AND def.position = 1;
```

Is there a way to get the entries for each entry that has duplicates (i.e. the complement of the distinct set over some_date?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `having` clause to get the list of entries that are duplicated:

```
SELECT abc.entry
FROM table abc JOIN
     table1 def
     ON abc.entry = def.entry
WHERE def.created >= 'some_date' AND def.position = 1
group by abc.entry
having count(*) > 1
```

To get the list of rows, I would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (SELECT abc.*, count(*) over (partition by entry) as cnt
      FROM table abc JOIN
           table1 def
           ON abc.entry = def.entry
      WHERE def.created >= 'some_date' AND def.position = 1
     ) t
where cnt > 1;
```

EDIT:

I see the confusion over the terminology.  `DISTINCT` has a very particular meaning in SQL.  And, `DISTINCT ON` has a rather different meaning in Postgres.  I think you have to do this with a subquery:

```
select abc.*
from table abc left outer join
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (abc.entry) abc.* FROM table abc
      JOIN table1 def ON abc.entry = def.entry
      WHERE def.created >= 'some_date' AND def.position = 1
     ) f
     on abc.id = f.id
where f.id is NULL
```

A word of caution, though.  You are using `distinct on` without an `order by` clause.  The particular row being returned in the data is indeterminate.  You should add an `order by` to your original data and to the subquery here.

```
select abc.*
from table abc left outer join
     (SELECT abc.entry, max(abc.id) as maxid
      FROM table abc
      JOIN table1 def ON abc.entry = def.entry
      WHERE def.created >= 'some_date' AND def.position = 1
      group by abc.entry
     ) f
     on abc.id = f.maxid
where f.maxid is NULL
```

Comment: Sorry, neither of these quite gets me there.  The first query returns a list of entry, which I already have from my initial query.  If you correct the second query to use "abc.entry" on line 2, it returns a list of all lines where duplicates occur.  What I really need is the complement.  If I have sets {{1, A}, {1, B}, {2, A}, {2, B}, {3, A}, {4, A}, ...}, and I perform my initial query, I might get {{1,A}, {2,B}, {3,A}, {4,A}.  If I can find the IDs of {{1,B}, {2,A}}, those are the records, I want to delete.  I can't have them all mixed together.

Comment: @DarinPeterson . . . Do you have an `id` column in `abc`?

Comment: Yes, def has an id column, abc has an id column as well as the foreign key to def.id. "entry" is the key to def in my initial query.

Comment: @Darin _The first query returns a list of entry, which I already have from my initial query_ No, it returns the list of the rows with *duplicated* `abc.entry` and your query returns the list of all rows eliminating the duplicated `abc.entry` rows. The fisrt Gordon query answers what you asked: _Is there a way to get the entries for each entry that has duplicates_. The problem is what you asked is not what you want. Reword your question.

Comment: @Neto read the i.e., you must have missed that part, which clearly states that I want the complement of the DISTINCT query.  If you understand what the complement is, you understand what i am asking.  That should be clarification enough.

Comment: @Gordon, thank you for the reply.  Unable to get back to verify it, but will reply before the end of today.

Comment: @Gordon, unfortunately I cannot get this to work.  I copied the script verbatim, but I keep getting errors.  I realize if ORDER BY is important that I should use it, but it's not important in this case.  Two of the abc.id records are identical with the exception to the abc.id, and I don't care which one gets removed.